# urls.py entry for django v1.10 mysite.com:8000/index.html

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having trouble getting the url entry in my app's urls.py file how I want it.
When a person enters `mysite.com:8000/`, I want it to use the same view as `mysite.com:8000/index.html`  I can use `url(r'^index.html$', views.index, name='index'),` and the view is properly displayed when I type `mysite.com:8000/index.html` into the chrome address bar, or I can trim the `.html`off both the urls.py entry and the address bar and it's ok, but I figured with regex, I could get this to display for `/` or for `index*`

lots of googling hasn't let me to an answer yet...

EDIT:
update based on @moses:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^(index\.?[html]{,4})?$', views.index, name='index'),
#       url(r'^index$', views.index, name='index'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

now I get: "Exception Value:index() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern that matches 0 or 1 repetitions of `'index.html'` in the url i.e. either `^$` or `r'^index.html$'`:

```
>>> re.match(r'^(?:index\.html)?$', 'index.html')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='index.html'>
>>> re.match(r'^(?:index\.html)?$', '')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
>>> re.match(r'^(?:index\.html)?$', 'login')
>>>
```

And your Django url pattern becomes:

```
url(r'^(?:index.html)?$', views.index, name='index')
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/MVCPDN/2

Comment: thanks! what about an option for `index` or `index.htm` or such?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working.  I'll post my updated urls.py as an edit above

Comment: @Keith I missed the non grouping feature: `^(?:index\.?[html]{,4})?$`

Comment: perfect.  It works as just `.com/`, `.com/index`, `.com/index.html` and `.com/index.htm`.  Can you include this corrected regex in your answer so future searchers will see it there instead of the comments?